# Show more digits when using the str() function in R

Tags: r

In `RStudio`, I imported a file with a series of geocoordinates.  It looks like this:
[image]

When I apply a `str` function on the lat field like this

```
> str(GeoCodeCrashSite$V4)
```

I am getting this.

```
num [1:2075] 35.8 35.8 35.1 35.8 35.8 ...
```

Is there a way to keep the level of precision?

Comment: Try `dplyr::glimpse` as an alternative to `str`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't really have to do with geocoding. `str` doesn't modify the data at all.  If you want to view more digits when str is printing to the console you can specify that in the digits.d parameter

```
> testdat <- data.frame(x = c(1.12342341, 32.34234234))
> testdat
          x
1  1.123423
2 32.342342
> str(testdat)
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ x: num  1.12 32.34
> str(testdat, digits.d = 10)
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ x: num  1.12342341 32.34234234
```